# Mongo $match item in array

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I have a collection:

```
news: {
_id: ObjectId("abc"),
feed: ObjectId("123")
}
```

I want to match this to an array of ObjectIds:

```
feeds = [ObjectId("123"),ObjectId("456"),...]
```

I need to return only the news that are part of the feed (news with feed: ObjectId("123")). I have tried several alternatives with Mongodb 3.2 aggregation including:

```
{ $match: { feed: feeds}}
{ $match: $or: { feed: feeds}}
```

Is there a simple way to achieve this?
Side note: I'm using nodejs

Comment: have you tried [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/) operator ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@veeram, thank you.

I used $in:

```
$match: { feed: { $in: feeds} }
```